# How to implement a paper drop down menu in java gwt

Tags: java, gwt, polymer

I am trying to implement a drop down box using polymer `PaperDropdownMenu`. I'm adding a `PaperListBox` inside a `PaperDropdownMenu`.

```
 PaperDropdownMenu dropdownMenu = new PaperDropdownMenu();
 dropdownMenu.setLabel("Select Plant");

 PaperListBox paperMenu = new PaperListBox ();
 paperMenu.addStyleName("dropdown-content");
 PaperItem itemm1 = new PaperItem("Thulsi");
 paperMenu.add(itemm1);
 PaperItem itemm2 = new PaperItem("Hibiscus");
 paperMenu.add(itemm2);
 PaperItem itemm3 = new PaperItem("Pepper");
 paperMenu.add(itemm3);
 PaperItem itemm4 = new PaperItem("Chilli");
 paperMenu.add(itemm4);

 dropdownMenu.add(paperMenu);
```

but the `PaperListBox` is not getting added to `PaperDropdownMenu`.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you see it when you inspect the HTML?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin No, I am not able to see the paper list box in the HTML.Instead I am able to see a paper material which I didn't add.

Comment: @bhavanak, take a look at [this](https://vaadin.github.io/gwt-polymer-elements/demo/#paper/DropdownMenuSample), hope this helps!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer Thank you for the reply...but I want a solution without using UI Binder.